# Quelle est la différence entre « davantage » et « d'avantage » ?

Tags: orthographe

Cela fait un moment que j'hésite à poser la question, vu que je pensais que la réponse était suffisamment connue que pour n'avoir aucun intérêt.

Manifestement, j'ai [sous-estimé l'intérêt de cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/1056/revisions).

Donc:

Quelle est la différence entre *davantage* et *d'avantage* ?

Comment: Heu, Vous pouvez répéter la question ?

Comment: @chepseskaf Oups, merci!

Comment: « Elle avait peu d'avantages / Pour en avoir davantage / Elle s'en fit rajouter / À l'institut de beauté (ah ah ah !) »

Comment: @JPP: suite : “Davantage d'avantages / avantagent davantage” — Boby Lapointe, *Framboise*

Comment: Pfff, en voyant le titre de la question je me rue ici avec l'intention de faire la citation... mais trop tard. Mais combien on est de fans de Bobby ici ? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Davantage

Utilisé pour indiquer lors d'une comparaison qu'il y en a plus.

> Il y a davantage de lait dans le chocolat blanc.
>
> Contr: Il y a moins de lait dans le chocolat blanc.

Davantage est invariable.

Le CNRTL ajoute au sujet de l'étymologie:

> 1559 d'avantage que « plus que » (Amyot, Pélop., 43 ds Littré);

---

> D'avantage

Contraction de "de" avec "avantage". Ici avantage signifie bénéfice, profit, ou intérêt (c'est le contraire d'inconvénient).

> Je ne vois pas d'avantage à cette question
>
> Je ne vois pas d'intérêt à cette question
>
> Contr. Je ne vois pas d'inconvénient à cette question

D'avantage peut être mis au pluriel.

> Il y a beaucoup d'avantages à la clef

---

On peut aussi combiner les deux pour faire joli :

> Il y a davantage d'avantages à cette proposition!

Comment: Je pense que votre dernier exemple est une [paronomase](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronomase#Paronomase).

Comment: C'est dur de répondre quelque chose d'intéressant avec vous, ces derniers jours: vos réponses sont trop complètes et parfaites :)

Comment: @Shlublu Et trop rapide !!

Comment: @chepseskaf je ne suis pas persuadé pour la paronomase. C'est sans doute le cas, mais il y a peut-être une version plus évoluée car ici nous avons deux mots qui sont des homonymes. Mais peut-être pas. En tout cas c'est une expression intéressante.

Comment: Logiquement, si la paronomase traite le cas de mots paronymes, la figure de style équivalente avec des homonymes devrait être une [homonomase](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonomase). Zut, raté. [Quoique...](http://www.google.fr/search?q=homonomase)